# Echo batch file arrays using a variable for the index?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, echo

If I have a batch file and I am setting arrays with an index that is a variable

```
@echo off
SET x=1
SET myVar[%x%]=happy
```

How do I echo that to get "happy" ?

I've tried

```
ECHO %myVar[%x%]%
ECHO %%myVar[%x%]%%
ECHO myVar[%x%]
```

But none of them work.

It works fine if I use the actual number for the index

```
ECHO %myVar[1]%
```

But not if the index number is also a variable

Comment: I suggest you to review: [arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SET x=1
SET myVar[%x%]=happy

call echo %%myvar[%x%]%%
set myvar[%x%]
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%v in ('set myvar[%x%]')  do @echo %%v
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !myvar[%x%]!
endlocal
```

I would recommend you to use

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !myvar[%x%]!
endlocal
```

as it is a best performing way

Comment: Yes of course... and I even did that in another section of my code, but didn't put 2 and 2 together. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a special `!` character in batch to deal with your situation. Use `echo !myVar[%x%]!`, from [How to return an element of an array in Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799576/how-to-return-an-element-of-an-array-in-batch). `!` means delayed expansion. The variable `myVar` will not get expanded until after `%x%` is, yielding the expression you want.

Answer (score 3):

one way you can do this is to use

```
call echo %%myVar[%x%]%%
```

call lets you put variables in places where they wouldn't normally work, if you use the double percents