# echo batch file array element in for-loop using the iteration variable for the index?

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

This question is similar to that of [Echo batch file arrays using a variable for the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385885/echo-batch-file-arrays-using-a-variable-for-the-index)
but it doesn't answer my question.

I have a batch file that contains a list. I am iterating through a for loop and want to print out an element from the list with each iteration using the iteration number (i.e. `list[i]`)

I am using 
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

and I've tried using:

```
!list[%i%]!
%list[%i%]%
!list[!i!]!
```

I'm aware I could use `FOR /L` but this would not work in the context I want to use this.

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET list[0]=1
SET list[1]=2
SET list[2]=3
SET list[3]=4
SET list[4]=5
SET /a i=0
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
    echo list[!i!] = %list[!i!]%
    SET /a i+=1
)
```

Expected:

```
list[0] = 1
list[1] = 2
list[2] = 3
list[3] = 4
list[4] = 5
```

Actual:

```
list[0] = 
list[1] = 
list[2] = 
list[3] = 
list[4] =
```

Comment: `echo !list[%%G]!` - you don't need `i` (as `%%G` is your iterator). Also you probably want `FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,4)`

Comment: Or do a simple `set list[` this has the disadvantage that it is alpha sorted, i.e. 1,10,11,2 etc.

Comment: In case you can't use `for /l` you might use double delayed expansion with a pseudo call and doubled percent signs: `call echo list[!i!] = %%list[!i!]%%`

Comment: Was going to answer, but it got closed before I hit submit.. anyway. not sure why you needed to set a counter for a counter, `set /a i` is not needed. just do `FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,4) DO (echo list[%%G] = !list[%%G]!)`

Comment: Thanks for all the sugegstions, the answer is explained in great detail in the link this has been marked a duplicate of. For my particular issue, the best answer is 
from @LotPings using %% around the list[] variable.