# Count rows and columns using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to count the number of lines and columns that several files have. So far I managed to get the number of rows

```
@echo off
if exist counts.txt del counts.txt
for /R "path To folder" %%a in (*.txt) do call :sub %%a
goto :eof

:Sub
for /F %%c in ('type "%*" ^| find /c /v ""') do set rowCount=%%c
echo %*;%rowCount% >> counts.txt
```

This batch file saves file name and row count separated by `;`. What I got stuck with is the column count. Any idea?

Possibly the output will be

`file path;row count;col count`

Comment: Are you trying to count the columns in csv files?  Or are you looking for the maximum length of a row in each file, 1 character = 1 column?

Comment: columns in csv file, assuming comma as a delimiter. (so count of them plus 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

A basic `for` loop evaluates unquoted commas, spaces, tabs, and semicolons as delimiters.  The magic is that it'll correctly skip quoted commas.  To count columns in your CSV file, you could just `for %%I in (first line) do increment counter`.  **This will only work if your csv header row does not contain unquoted spaces or other delimiters.**  If you prefer to follow your original logic and count the number of commas, then see solution #2 below.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if exist counts.txt del counts.txt
for /R "path To folder" %%a in (*.txt) do call :sub "%%~fa"
goto :eof

:Sub
setlocal
for /F %%c in ('type "%~1" ^| find /c /v ""') do set rowCount=%%c

:: read first line of file.txt into var
set /P "line=" <"%~1"

:: delayed expansion prevents evaluation of special characters
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for %%I in (!line!) do set /a count += 1
endlocal & set "colCount=%count%"

:: If you want to echo only filename.ext to counts.txt, un-rem this and
:: use %filename% instead of %~1 in your echo. 
rem for %%I in ("%~1") do set "filename=%%~nxI"

echo %~1;%rowCount%;%colCount% >> counts.txt
endlocal
```

---

#### Solution 2:

Uses a `:length` function to get the length of the header row with and without commas, and returns the difference + 1.  (`:length` function logic is based on [jeb's `:StringLength`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674904/1683264).)  **This will only work if your csv files have no header rows, or if the header rows are guaranteed not to contain quoted commas.**

```
@echo off
setlocal

if exist counts.txt del counts.txt
for /R "path To folder" %%a in (*.txt) do call :sub "%%~fa"
goto :eof

:Sub
setlocal
for /F %%c in ('type "%~1" ^| find /c /v ""') do set rowCount=%%c

:: read first line of file.txt into var
set /P "line=" <"%~1"
set colCount=0

:: delayed expansion prevents evaluation of special characters
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=!line:"=!
call :length b4 "!line!"
call :length after "!line:,=!"
endlocal & set /a colCount = %b4% - %after% + 1

:: If you want to echo only filename.ext to counts.txt, un-rem this and
:: use %filename% instead of %~1 in your echo.  
rem for %%I in ("%~1") do set "filename=%%~nxI"

echo %~1;%rowCount%;%colCount% >> counts.txt
echo %~1;%rowCount%;%colCount%
endlocal
goto :EOF

:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "tmpstr=%~2"
set ret=0
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
        set /a "ret += %%I"
        set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
goto :EOF
```